# Grails: Plugin not found for name [acegi] and version [0.5.2]

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy, grails-plugin

I am using `grails 1.3.7` and I'm trying to install `acegi` plugin with below command getting above error

```
install-plugin acegi 0.5.2
```

**BuildConfig.groovy:**

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.13'
    }
}
```

In my BuildConfig.groovy I have un commented to maven repo's to resolve plugins but still its doesn't make any difference.

Is there any way to make install `acegi` plugin with above command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try adding these two to repositories

```
repositories {
  ....
  mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
  mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
}
```